# best online service to backup Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I've been making some tweaks as well as adding finishing touches to an app I've been working on. I just noticed my computer started to load very slowly when compiling the app. after several screen crashes and freezes I decided to reboot in a various number of ways. http://www.macworld.com/article/2018853/when-good-macs-go-bad-steps-to-take-when-your-mac-wont-start-up.html

Thankfully I still have all my files and multiple Xcode snapshots for me to use. I don't have a flash drive on me and was wondering what would be the best online service to store my app for the time being?

I know this might be a tad unrelated but I feel this is an important topic and if anyone has any suggestions about which service to use for this task, I'd love to hear it ...ie Google drive , Dropbox, etc...I'm a noob with these services

Comment: If you're not using source code control and you're not backing up your computer (Time Machine?) regularly, then you're doing it wrong. Sending a zip file to a cloud service like Dropbox or Google Drive is just another form of backup you can do on top of the others.

Comment: Yes I am considering both of those. If I may ask which do you prefer?

Comment: It doesn't matter which you use (Dropbox or Google Drive). They are the same when it comes to storing a file. Just make sure you use one in addition to source control and regular computer backups.

Comment: Ok. What do you mean source control? Never heard of that

Comment: Subversion (svn) or git are two source code control systems supported by Xcode. If you don't know what source code control is then I highly recommend you do a Google search on the term.

Comment: Also I never really got acquainted with the time machine. I just create snapshots from Xcode.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answers. I think I'll try google drive just to ease anxiety. I'll also do a little research and manually clean my Mac a bit

Answer (score 1):

You can use bitbucket.com, it's free for small projects.

Comment: Thank you both for you answers

Answer (score 0):

Github is the best repository, it allows you to backup your project,
 you can clone it anywhere at any system.
And you can update your project as well.
 Along with this, You can make it private.
http://git-scm.com/docs

There is another option if you don't want this to be some console 
there is an iCloud drive available in Favourites, that is located in left side of any Finder Folder.